# Why does order of 3 loops in Floyd-Warshall matters?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

In popoular implementation we use three loops, loop variables say i,j,k. Here i & j are used for indicating two vertices' source & destination respectively and so 'k' represents the 'intermediate' vertex. If i place loop with loop variable 'k' 3rd instead of placing it 1st i get wrong answer. Why?

Comment: I dont understand what you exactly do, please show us your new algorithm maybe we understand that :)

Answer (score 5):

Here's the idea behind Floyd-Warshall algorithm:

```
if:
i is connected to k and
k is connected to j
then if i and j are not connected,
create a connection between i and j
```

Alternative explanation:

```
if:
i -> k and
k -> j
then if not i -> j
create i -> j
```

What I am trying to say is that k is going to be in the middle of the logical connection. The middle vertex k is responsible of giving permission for the the N neighbors vertices to have direct connection.

The above algorithm must be applied on |V| vertices, and therefore the loop on k must be the most outer for loop.

Example:

```
DiGraph:
Vertices: 0,1,2
Edges: (0,1), (1,2)
Representation: 0 -> 1 -> 2
```

Algorithm:

```
k = 0
i = 0 ignore because k = i
i = 1 false because 1 -> 0 is wrong
i = 2 false because 2 -> 0 is wrong

k = 1
i = 0 true because 0 -> 1
j = 0 ignore because i = j
j = 1 ignore because j = k
j = 2 true because 1 -> 2
Since 0 -> 2 does not exist, create this edge
i = 1 ignore because i = k
i = 2 false because 2 -> 1 is wrong

k = 2
i = 0 true because we created this edge in the previous iteration
j = 0 ignore because i = j
j = 1 false because 2 -> 1 is wrong
j = 2 ignore because j = k
i = 1 true because 1 -> 2
j = 0 false because 2 -> 0 is wrong
j = 1 ignore because i = j
j = 2 ignore because j = k
i = 2 ignore because i = k
```

So in conclusion,
k needed to execute |V| times
i needed to execute |V| times for each k 
j needed to execute |V| times for each successful i on i -> k

Time complexity: O(n<sup>3</sup>)

Note: If you want to apply the algorithm or play with it so that you understand better how it works, please check my [Github repo on the GraphADT](https://github.com/amirbawab/GraphADT), the method name is `transitiveClosure()`. The method is implemented in the [Graph.java file](https://github.com/amirbawab/GraphADT/blob/master/Graph.java).

Comment: Intuitive explanation, +1 for this.

Comment: even if I did distance[i][j] = distance[i][k] + distance[k][j] arent we iterating over all possible combinations of i, j and k so this will give us the correct answer? The only way I can imagine this doesnt work is when the order we iterate over i, j, k makes all the difference. Any help would be appreciated